# UITableView section header appearing over table header view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating a custom view for both a section header and a table header ofa `UITableView`. The problem is that the section view (in green) is appearing over the table header view (in red)

[image]

The code for the table header view is

```
self.headerImageView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.headerImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerImageView;
```

and i set its frame here

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.headerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.frame), 100);
}
```

The code for the section header

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    return view;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the code all in -(void)viewDidLoad, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.headerImageView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _headerImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    _headerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.frame), 100);
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _headerImageView;
}
```

I found that -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called many times while scrolling the table. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I eventually figured this out that the frame has to be set in the `viewDidLoad`.